# Not able to update the state in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am making a basic coronavirus tracker application where my incoming data looks like this:

```
    [
{
"provinceName": "Canada",
"confirmedCases": "66,780",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "4,628"
},
{
"provinceName": "Newfoundland and Labrador",
"confirmedCases": "261",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "3"
},
{
"provinceName": "Prince Edward Island",
"confirmedCases": "27",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
},
{
"provinceName": "Nova Scotia",
"confirmedCases": "1,008",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "46"
},
{
"provinceName": "New Brunswick",
"confirmedCases": "120",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
},
{
"provinceName": "Quebec",
"confirmedCases": "36,150",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "2,725"
},
{
"provinceName": "Ontario",
"confirmedCases": "19,944",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "1,599"
},
{
"provinceName": "Manitoba",
"confirmedCases": "284",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "7"
},
{
"provinceName": "Saskatchewan",
"confirmedCases": "544",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "6"
},
{
"provinceName": "Alberta",
"confirmedCases": "6,098",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "115"
},
{
"provinceName": "British Columbia",
"confirmedCases": "2,315",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "127"
},
{
"provinceName": "Yukon",
"confirmedCases": "11",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
},
{
"provinceName": "Northwest Territories",
"confirmedCases": "5",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
},
{
"provinceName": "Nunavut",
"confirmedCases": "0",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
},
{
"provinceName": "Repatriated travellers",
"confirmedCases": "13",
"probableCases": "0",
"deaths": "0"
}
]
```

I am rendering it to a React svg map where i am expecting the data as multiple arrays inside one array like this:

```
data: [
  ["PE", 67],
  ["MB", 75],
  ["SK", 43],
  ["AB", 50],
  ["BC", 88],
  ["NU", 21],
  ["NT", 43],
  ["YT", 21],
  ["QC", 60],
  ["ON", 19],
  ["NB", 4],
  ["NS", 44],
  ["NF", 38],
],`enter code here`
```

I am trying to update the state data after i fetch the json from axios, i am trying to process it in componentDidUpdate to get it in the desired format. But when i am trying to set the state inside componentDidUpdate() it os not working, I want the fetched data in the above mentioned format.
How can i set the dataArray to data(state)?

Here is the React class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChoroplethMap from "../ChoroplethMap";
import axios from "axios";

class Canada extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      // ["PE", 67],
      // ["MB", 75],
      // ["SK", 43],
      // ["AB", 50],
      // ["BC", 88],
      // ["NU", 21],
      // ["NT", 43],
      // ["YT", 21],
      // ["QC", 60],
      // ["ON", 19],
      // ["NB", 4],
      // ["NS", 44],
      // ["NF", 38],
    ],
    isLoaded: false,
    rawdata: [],
    isDataSet: false,
  };
  getData() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/h3")
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(data => ({
          provinceName: `${data.provinceName}`,
          confirmedCases: `${data.confirmedCases}`,
          probableCases: `${data.probableCases}`,
          deaths: `${data.deaths}`
        }))
      )
      .then(rawdata => {
        this.setState({
          rawdata,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.isLoaded === true) {
      let dataArray = [];
      let insideArray;
      this.state.rawdata.forEach(element => {
        if (element.provinceName !== "Canada") {
          insideArray = new Array();
          var sexy = parseInt(element.confirmedCases.replace(",", ""));
          var provinceName = element.provinceName;
          if (provinceName === "New Brunswick") {
            insideArray.push("NB");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Manitoba") {
            insideArray.push("MB");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Newfoundland and Labrador") {
            insideArray.push("NF");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Nova Scotia") {
            insideArray.push("NS");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Saskatchewan") {
            insideArray.push("SK");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Alberta") {
            insideArray.push("AB");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Prince Edward Island") {
            insideArray.push("PE");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Quebec") {
            insideArray.push("QC");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Ontario") {
            insideArray.push("ON");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "British Columbia") {
            insideArray.push("BC");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Yukon") {
            insideArray.push("YT");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Northwest Territories") {
            insideArray.push("NT");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Nunavut") {
            insideArray.push("NU");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          } else if (provinceName === "Northwest Territories") {
            insideArray.push("NT");
            insideArray.push(sexy);
          }
          dataArray.push(insideArray);
        }
      });
      dataArray.pop();
      if (this.state.isDataSet == false) {

        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.data, ...dataArray],
          isDataSet: true,
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw"
        }}
      >
        <ChoroplethMap data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Canada;
```

Comment: create a function that do what you have in `componentDidUpdate` and activate it after the data response. that's because I think that update the state is not update the component.. do if you try to console.log, you will see nothing, because the component dont update,, the state update

Answer (score 0):

You should update the state only one time:
 - Receive the data,
 - Process it,
 - Set the state

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChoroplethMap from "../ChoroplethMap";
import axios from "axios";

class Canada extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    data: [
        // ["PE", 67],
        // ["MB", 75],
        // ["SK", 43],
        // ["AB", 50],
        // ["BC", 88],
        // ["NU", 21],
        // ["NT", 43],
        // ["YT", 21],
        // ["QC", 60],
        // ["ON", 19],
        // ["NB", 4],
        // ["NS", 44],
        // ["NF", 38],
      ],
      isLoaded: false,
      rawdata: [],
      isDataSet: false,
    };
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    this.getData = this.processRawData.bind(this);
  }


  getData() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/h3")
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(data => ({
          provinceName: `${data.provinceName}`,
          confirmedCases: `${data.confirmedCases}`,
          probableCases: `${data.probableCases}`,
          deaths: `${data.deaths}`
        }))
      )
      .then(rawdata => {
        // === Right here process the data ===
        let data = this.rocessRawData(rawdata);
        // === =========================== ===
        this.setState({
          rawdata,
          data,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }


  processRawData(rawdata)
  {
    let dataArray = [];
    let insideArray;
    rawdata.forEach(element => {
      if (element.provinceName !== "Canada") {
        insideArray = new Array();
        var sexy = parseInt(element.confirmedCases.replace(",", ""));
        var provinceName = element.provinceName;
        if (provinceName === "New Brunswick") {
          insideArray.push("NB");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Manitoba") {
          insideArray.push("MB");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Newfoundland and Labrador") {
          insideArray.push("NF");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Nova Scotia") {
          insideArray.push("NS");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Saskatchewan") {
          insideArray.push("SK");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Alberta") {
          insideArray.push("AB");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Prince Edward Island") {
          insideArray.push("PE");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Quebec") {
          insideArray.push("QC");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Ontario") {
          insideArray.push("ON");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "British Columbia") {
          insideArray.push("BC");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Yukon") {
          insideArray.push("YT");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Northwest Territories") {
          insideArray.push("NT");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Nunavut") {
          insideArray.push("NU");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        } else if (provinceName === "Northwest Territories") {
          insideArray.push("NT");
          insideArray.push(sexy);
        }
        dataArray.push(insideArray);
      }
    });
    dataArray.pop();
    return dataArray;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          width: "100vw"
        }}
      >
        <ChoroplethMap data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Canada;
```

Comment: That's wrong. State is mutable. You can set state infinite amount of time

Comment: I know, @SyedMisharNewaz ... I said _should_ , not "must"... because there is no need to update in two separate places, could be easily done in the same place and avoid some possible troubles with updating it in two different places (according to what is shown in the case)

Comment: PS: Also, it is recommended that we try to update the state as few times as possible (always without compromising complexity), as updating the state will trigger a re-rendering of the component, which can lead to other problems and/or performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason is, whenever you define a function in React or ES6 class in general, you need to do either one of this:

1. Bind it to the context using `this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)` in constructor
2. Use this syntax, `getData = () = { }`

As those were not binded,

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}
```

This getData() never ran and

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.isLoaded === true) {
    ....
  }
}
```

This condition was never true